# Sencha touch2, data in localstore not getting into localstorage

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Model:

```
Ext.define('SkSe.model.PlacesLocal',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    config:{
        fields:['id', 'name','icon','required_stamps', 'active_stamps','description', 'campaign_id', 'user_favorites' , 'live_action_number'],
         proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id  : 'local-places-id'

    }

    }

});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('SkSe.store.PlacesLocal', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        storeId: 'PlacesLocal',
        model: "SkSe.model.PlacesLocal",
         sorters: 'name',
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function (item) {
                return item.get('name')[0];
            }
        }, 
        groupDir: 'DESC'


    }
});
```

Offline - Online Store sync:

```
Ext.define('SkSe.store.Places',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',

    config:{

        autoLoad:true,
        autoSync:true, 
        model:'SkSe.model.Places',
        sorters: 'name',
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function (item) {
                return item.get('name')[0];
            }
        }, 
        groupDir: 'DESC',
        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            url:'http://localhost/campaigns/',
            reader:{
                type:'json',
                //name of array where the results are stored
                rootProperty:'results'
            }
        },

        listeners: {
                load: function() {

                    var PlacesLocal = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('PlacesLocal');
                    // Clear proxy from offline store

                      if (navigator.onLine) {
                   console.log("Hm");

                    // Loop through records and fill the offline store
                    this.each(function(record) {

                        PlacesLocal.add(record.data);

                    });

                    // Sync the offline store
                    PlacesLocal.sync();
                      }
                }

    }
    }
});
```

Apparently placesLocalstore does get the data, but for some reason it doesn't get stored in localstorage.

Key local-places-id appears in localstorage but without any data.

Comment: Do you see "console.log("Hm");" in the output?

Comment: yeah shows just fine.

Comment: Have you considered leveraging the work of others? [Ext.ux.proxy.ProxyCache](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/ext-ux-proxy-proxycache), or [Ext.ux.OfflineSyncStore](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/ext-ux-offlinesyncstore), for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you do that:

```
PlacesLocal.add(record.data);
```

There's an `id` field with a value in `record.data`. Hence, the record won't be considered new. It won't be considered modified either, because it has not be modified, and it won't be considered deleted either (the explaination is left as an exercice to the reader).

In other words, for the store, there's nothing to sync. Mission complete.

Here's the code of `getNewRecords`, that is used in the `sync` method:

```
function() {
    return this.data.filterBy(function(item) {
        // only want phantom records that are valid
        return item.phantom === true && item.isValid();
    }).items;
}
```

I suppose you've guessed what you need to do by now, but let me be voluble:

```
var recordsData = store.getRange().map(function(record) { return record.data }),
    newRecords = PlacesLocal.add(recordsData);

Ext.each(newRecords, function(record) {
    record.phantom = true;
});

// Now it should have plenty of work!
PlacesLocal.sync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is the id, so with the copy method you fix the problem:

```
// Loop through records and fill the offline store
this.each(function (item, index, length){
    var newItem = item.copy()
    PlacesLocal.add(newItem);

});
```